# Redmine Changeset display in details of Issue

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

is there any plug in for redmine, to display linked changesets for a specific issue?
I specified Repository (Mercurial) and I would like to see changesets clicking to an Issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a plugin for this - **it's built-in**. All you need to do when committing to your repository is to enter the issue number preceded by a `#` in your message.

For an example, check out an issue on the redmine web site: http://www.redmine.org/issues/6317

There's a column containing *Associated revisions* which contains source control changesets. They appear on this issue because they have `#6317` in their message.

Depending on the configuration of redmine, a keyword before the issue number is needed in order to have the changeset linked to the issue. Those keywords can be modified in the settings of redmine:

[image: redmine settings]

Examples for the above settings:

- `refs #1234`
- `references #1234, #1337`
- `issue #1234 #1337 & #1001`

If you'd like to omit keywords and simply link a changeset to all issue numbers found in the log message, enter a `*` into the *Referencing keywords* textbox.

Finally, in order to have redmine check for *new* changesets and parse the repository's log messages, you'll need to click on the *Repository* tab, or configure a rake task to do it regularly.

Comment: Ok, It is really working, there are some keywords available to specify in comment when you making a commit change to repository,    `for referencing issues: refs, references, IssueID for fixing issues: fixes, closes`  [RedmineSettings](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineSettings#Referencing-issues-in-commit-messages)

Comment: @Alexei Of course you're right - I added some lines concerning keywords as well as some examples to the answer. If you prefer no keywords, try the configuration with a `*` (that's how redmine.org seems to be configured).